# Google Cloud: Quota 'C2_CPUS' exceeded Limit: 0.0 in region us-central, but the limit is unlimited

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a server to run some code on Google Cloud and am receiving the error

```
Quota 'C2_CPUS' exceeded Limit: 0.0 in region us-central
```

[image]

When I follow [the instructions listed on other answers](http://Quota%20%27C2_CPUS%27%20exceeded%20Limit:%200.0%20in%20region%20us-central), they tell me

```
In the Cloud Console, go to the Quotas page.

Go to Quotas
On the Quotas page, select the quotas that you want to change.
At the top of the page, click Edit quotas.
Fill out your name, email, and phone number, and then click Next.
Fill in your quota request, and then click Done.
Submit your request.
```

When I go to that page and click "edit quotas" it just opens up a side panel that says

```
Select one or more quotas to edit.
```

When I click on the regions nothing happens, I can't select them, and why do they say unlimited if the quota is exceeded? It also looks like us-central1 doesn't exist, there's just uscentral1-a, uscentral1-b ...

[image]

I just want to get a server running that I can train some machine learning model's on.

Answer (score 1):

us-central1 was on the last page, it was clickable, I clicked it and entered 100 as the new limit

[image]